# How to update value inside object in object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an Object with composition BDM.
It includes an object inside an object.

I would like to update a value once the object has a specific string.

I can update the Object with the same value, however, I couldn't get the dynamic value with child object.

This is the Object I have.

```
    $data.timerObjJson; 

        [
          {
            "persistenceId": 322,
             "persistenceId_string": "322",
             "persistenceVersion": 0,
             "persistenceVersion_string": "0",
             "recommandation": "Recommandation  1",
                     "timerTask": [
                            {
                              "persistenceId": 508,
                              "persistenceId_string": "508",
                              "persistenceVersion": 0,
                              "persistenceVersion_string": "0",
                              "title": "Task1",
                              "startdate": "2019-02-13",
                              "enddate": "2019-02-13",
                              "statusTask": "decline",
                              "declineReason": ""
                            },
                            {
                              "persistenceId": 511,
                              "persistenceId_string": "508",
                              "persistenceVersion": 0,
                              "persistenceVersion_string": "0",
                              "title": "Task1",
                              "startdate": "2019-02-13",
                              "enddate": "2019-02-13",
                              "statusTask": "decline",
                              "declineReason": ""
                            }
                          ],
                          "statusRec": "In process"
                        },
                        {
                          "persistenceId": 323,
                          "persistenceId_string": "323",
                          "persistenceVersion": 0,
                          "persistenceVersion_string": "0",
                          "recommandation": "Recommandation 2",
                          "timerTask": [
                            {
                              "persistenceId": 509,
                              "persistenceId_string": "509",
                              "persistenceVersion": 0,
                              "persistenceVersion_string": "0",
                              "title": "Task2",
                              "startdate": "2019-02-13",
                              "enddate": "2019-03-02",
                              "statusTask": "decline",
                              "declineReason": ""
                            },
                            {
                              "persistenceId": 509,
                              "persistenceId_string": "509",
                              "persistenceVersion": 0,
                              "persistenceVersion_string": "0",
                              "title": "Task2",
                              "startdate": "2019-02-13",
                              "enddate": "2019-03-02",
                              "statusTask": "decline",
                              "declineReason": ""
                            }
                          ],
                          "statusRec": "In process"
                        }
                      ]
```

This is what I tried to get return the `statusTask` and

```
    $data.getDone:
    var obj = [];
    for(var i in $data.timerObjJson){
        for(var j in $data.timerObjJson[i].timerTask){

            var thisObj = {};
            thisObj = $data.timerObjJson[i].timerTask[j]; 
            obj.push(thisObj);
        }
    } 

    var objArray=[];
            for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {    
             objArray.push(obj[i].statusTask); 
    }

   function isBelowThreshold(currentValue) {
      return currentValue == "done";
   }
   return objArray.every(isBelowThreshold)
```

And I tried to update the `statusRec` using by let as belows

```
      var data = $data.timerObjJson; 
      var done = $data.getDone; //true or false 

      let arr = data;

      const status = "In process";
      if (done == true){
           arr.find(v => v.statusRec == status).statusRec = "DONE";
       }
      return data;
```

But what I need to update is each `statusRec` depends on `timerTask.statusTask`'s status.

For example, once all `timerTask.statusTask` changed "done"
the `statusRec` should update to "Done".

Comment: All four `timerTask.statusTask` must be done? Or just groups of two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question actually , if i understood the question correctly , you're looking for if timerTask.statusTask has value of 'done' of both 2 objects it changes statusRec to 'done' of the same object so you can reach that approach by using filter array method in JavaScript here is an example:

```js
    let array = [
  {
    "persistenceId": 322,
     "persistenceId_string": "322",
     "persistenceVersion": 0,
     "persistenceVersion_string": "0",
     "recommandation": "Recommandation  1",
     "timerTask": [
        {
          "persistenceId": 508,
          "persistenceId_string": "508",
          "persistenceVersion": 0,
          "persistenceVersion_string": "0",
          "title": "Task1",
          "startdate": "2019-02-13",
          "enddate": "2019-02-13",
          "statusTask": "decline",
          "declineReason": ""
        },
        {
          "persistenceId": 511,
          "persistenceId_string": "508",
          "persistenceVersion": 0,
          "persistenceVersion_string": "0",
          "title": "Task1",
          "startdate": "2019-02-13",
          "enddate": "2019-02-13",
          "statusTask": "decline",
          "declineReason": ""
        }
      ],
      "statusRec": "In process"
    },
    {
      "persistenceId": 323,
      "persistenceId_string": "323",
      "persistenceVersion": 0,
      "persistenceVersion_string": "0",
      "recommandation": "Recommandation 2",
      "timerTask": [
        {
          "persistenceId": 509,
          "persistenceId_string": "509",
          "persistenceVersion": 0,
          "persistenceVersion_string": "0",
          "title": "Task2",
          "startdate": "2019-02-13",
          "enddate": "2019-03-02",
          "statusTask": "decline",
          "declineReason": ""
        },
        {
          "persistenceId": 509,
          "persistenceId_string": "509",
          "persistenceVersion": 0,
          "persistenceVersion_string": "0",
          "title": "Task2",
          "startdate": "2019-02-13",
          "enddate": "2019-03-02",
          "statusTask": "done",
          "declineReason": ""
        }
      ],
      "statusRec": "In process"
    }
]


function TheSameInAllObjects(status) {
  if (!(status && status.length)) return true; // If there is no status, or if it is empty, they are all the same, aren't they?
  let compare = status[0].statusTask;
  return status.every( item => item.statusTask === compare);
}

array.filter(data => {
   let obj = {}
   data['timerTask'].filter(result => {
    if(result.statusTask === 'done'){
      obj = data
      if(TheSameInAllObjects(obj['timerTask']) === true){
        return data.statusRec = 'done'
      }
    }
  })
})

console.log(array)
```

and you can check here for both has the same value of 'done'

```js
let array = [
  {
    "persistenceId": 322,
     "persistenceId_string": "322",
     "persistenceVersion": 0,
     "persistenceVersion_string": "0",
     "recommandation": "Recommandation  1",
     "timerTask": [
        {
          "persistenceId": 508,
          "persistenceId_string": "508",
          "persistenceVersion": 0,
          "persistenceVersion_string": "0",
          "title": "Task1",
          "startdate": "2019-02-13",
          "enddate": "2019-02-13",
          "statusTask": "decline",
          "declineReason": ""
        },
        {
          "persistenceId": 511,
          "persistenceId_string": "508",
          "persistenceVersion": 0,
          "persistenceVersion_string": "0",
          "title": "Task1",
          "startdate": "2019-02-13",
          "enddate": "2019-02-13",
          "statusTask": "decline",
          "declineReason": ""
        }
      ],
      "statusRec": "In process"
    },
    {
      "persistenceId": 323,
      "persistenceId_string": "323",
      "persistenceVersion": 0,
      "persistenceVersion_string": "0",
      "recommandation": "Recommandation 2",
      "timerTask": [
        {
          "persistenceId": 509,
          "persistenceId_string": "509",
          "persistenceVersion": 0,
          "persistenceVersion_string": "0",
          "title": "Task2",
          "startdate": "2019-02-13",
          "enddate": "2019-03-02",
          "statusTask": "done",
          "declineReason": ""
        },
        {
          "persistenceId": 509,
          "persistenceId_string": "509",
          "persistenceVersion": 0,
          "persistenceVersion_string": "0",
          "title": "Task2",
          "startdate": "2019-02-13",
          "enddate": "2019-03-02",
          "statusTask": "done",
          "declineReason": ""
        }
      ],
      "statusRec": "In process"
    }
]


function TheSameInAllObjects(status) {
  if (!(status && status.length)) return true; // If there is no status, or if it is empty, they are all the same, aren't they?
  let compare = status[0].statusTask;
  return status.every( item => item.statusTask === compare);
}

array.filter(data => {
   let obj = {}
   data['timerTask'].filter(result => {
    if(result.statusTask === 'done'){
      obj = data
      if(TheSameInAllObjects(obj['timerTask']) === true){
        return data.statusRec = 'done'
      }
    }
  })
})

console.log(array)
```

i have updated my answer to achieve your goal

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think it is almost what I want. Then, is it possible to update the statusRec as "done"  when all statusTask are done. In the example, if one of the value is done the statusRec updated "done". I would like to update once all statusTask are "done".  I will try to update the value based on your code. Thanks a lot

Comment: no problem happy to help , you can use the same filter method and to return the desired object and do some extra operations to reach your goal

Comment: I am in lost while I tried to create the operation. Would you add the code if possible? Thanks in advanced.  I tried to do, but I cannot get the  statusTasks  of each object. 
 function isBelowThreshold(currentValue) {
  return currentValue === "done";
}

var array1 =  ["done","done"] // get statusTasks 

array.filter(data => {
  data["timerTask"].filter(result => { 
    var result1 = result.statusTask;
    
    //if(result.statusTask === "done"){
    if(array1.every(isBelowThreshold)){
      return data.statusRec = "Done" ;
    }
  });
});
 
 
//console.log(array)

Comment: @Jane i have updated my answer to answer your question

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! This works perfectly. The code looks still difficult for me, however, I will try to understand. I appreciate your help. Regards, :)

Answer (score 1):

this is  how you can update an object:

```js
var object = {
  "name": "aziz",
  "address": {
    "ville": "MTL",
    "street": {
      "name": "Bonnier",
      "number": 8012
    }
  }
}


object = { ...object,
  address: { ...object.address,
    street: {
      ...object.address.street,
      number: 9000
    }
  }
}

console.log(object);

var object2 = {
  "name": "aziz",
  "address": {
    "ville": "MTL",
    "street": {
      "name": "Bonnier",
      "number": 8012
    }
  }
}


/* 2 method */
object2.address.street.number = 10000;

console.log(object2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, then my object has another object inside. I couldn't adjust the code you provided. Could you give me more idea about that? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Updated with an object inside another object

Comment: I am sorry to bother you again, In my case, I need to update object.name once all address.number changed specific value for example 8022

Comment: sorry i didn't get what you want i ll delete my answer